# How to see if a week past from a specific date?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a `VB.Net` WinForm application. In which every week a setting will have to get reset and another setting(the date) will have to be updated.

For example:

The date is `7/17/18`. On the `7/24/18`, the setting will be reset and the date setting will be `7/24/18` so the function can go on. I know how to update and reset the setting. I just don't know how to say "a week from this date".

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Something like `If SettingsDate.AddDays(7) >= DateTime.Now then (...)`. If the date is stored as string, see `DateTime.TryParse()` to convert the string back to a `DateTime` value. It also depends on how you calculate the dates and the UI Culture in use. You should specify whether the these parameters are constant or not (always `InvariantCulture` or not and same Time zone or not).

Comment: Any `Date` has a `DayOfYear` property. Your date 7/17/18 would give you 198 as the `DayOfYear`. If you divide 198 by 7 and fiddle around with your local date settings (what is the first week of a year and what is the first day of a week) you can figure out that your date is probably in calendar week 29/2018.

Comment: @jimi Shouldn't comparer be `<=` or the order of comparison should be changed? Your sample will return true if he current date is before 7 days after the settings date. For readability - perhaps the sample should even be `If DateTime.Now >= SettingsDate.AddDays(7) Then`

Comment: @David Wilson  You're probably right. I mainly considered the *I just don't know how to say a week from this date*, adding some notes so that someone could eventually pick them up and give a full answer. I might choose `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) > RefDate then *Past due, do something*`. It depends on how this app operates.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create an application level setting with user scope to store your last date, then you can compare the current date with the stored date to see if 7 days have past.

There are a few ways you could handle it, but to avoid culture issues, personally I have found that the easiest way is to store the date as a string in the international date format, so no matter what format the system uses for dates, the date will ALWAYS be in a recognisable format.

This method eliminates problems that could come up if the system's regional settings change:

```
My.Settings.DateSetting = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

To see if a week has passed from your previous date:

```
If Date.Today >= Cdate(My.Settings.DateSetting).AddDays(7) Then

    'Do your stuff here
    ' ...        

    'Add one week to the previous date and save the setting
    My.Settings.DateSetting = CDate(My.Settings.DateSetting).AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    My.Settings.Save()

End If
```

Comment: Thanks! The date setting is not a string I set it to a date. Would it already be in the “yyyy-MM-dd” format?

Comment: @JakeTous No, the system formats the date according to your regional settings.  So if a date is saved and you change your regional settings, it might cause problems

Comment: @JakeTous To see the exact format used for your date, just use to see the value MessageBox.Show(My.Settings.DateSetting)